# Getting right output in codelite IDE, But getting bunch of errors in cmd ,why?

Tags: c++, gcc

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
string countAndSay(int);
int main(){
    
    int n{};
    cin >> n;
    cout << countAndSay(n) << endl;
    
    return 0;
    }
    
string countAndSay(int n ){
    static string s{"1"};
    int count{n},special{n};
    string one{"1"},two{"2"},three{"3"},trans{};
    
    for(size_t i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++){
        char c0 = s[i-1], c = s[i], c2 = s[i+1], c3 = s[i+2];
        if(c!=c2 && c!=c0){
            trans+=one+c;
        }
        if(c==c2 && c!=c3 && c!=c0){
            trans+=two+c;
        }
        if(c==c2 && c==c3 && c!=c0){
            trans+=three+c;
        }
    }
    s.replace(0, s.size() , trans);
    
    if(special != 1){
        int N = --count;
        if(N == 1)
            return s;
        else
            return countAndSay(N);
    }else 
        return "1";
}
```

**these are the errors in cmd**

C:\Users\saurabh rajput>gcc -o cas cas.cpp
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `std::cin' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x2a): undefined reference to` std::istream::operator>>(int&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `std::cout' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to` std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x59): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to` std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x6d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0xa4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to` __cxa_guard_acquire'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0xe6): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0xfe): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x10d): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_release' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x123): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x139): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x161): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x16b): undefined reference to` std::allocator::allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x186): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x193): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x19d): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x1c5): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x1d2): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x204): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator[](unsigned int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x21d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x239): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator[](unsigned int)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x255): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned int)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator+=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x2ad): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x2f8): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator+=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x305): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x350): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::operator+=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x35d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x370): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::size() const'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x38f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::replace(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x3b7): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x3da): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x3f0): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator const&)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x3fd): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x40a): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x417): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x424): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x431): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x442): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x457): undefined reference to `__cxa_guard_abort' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x46d): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x483): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x491): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x49f): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4ad): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4bb): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4c9): undefined reference to` std::allocator::~allocator()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4da): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4e7): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x4f4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x501): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x523): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text+0x544): undefined reference to` std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text$*ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5*[_*ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5*]+0x17): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text$_ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5_[__ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5_]+0x31): undefined reference to` std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >::append(unsigned int, char)'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.text$*ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5*[_*ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5*]+0x40): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()' c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to` __gxx_personality_v0'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\SAURAB~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccsa08IU.o:cas.cpp:(.eh_frame$*ZStplIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEENSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIT_T0_T1_EERKS8_S5*+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Use `g++` to compile C++ code.

Comment: sorry bro, when i used g++ also getting errors ,.............C:\Users\saurabh rajput>g++ -o cas cas.cpp

C:\Users\saurabh rajput>cas.exe
3

Comment: /home/keith/builds/mingw/gcc-9.2.0-mingw32-cross-native/mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:1067: std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[](std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::reference = char&; std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type = unsigned int]: Assertion '__pos <= size()' failed.

Comment: although I am not getting so many like with gcc but still in problem

Comment: That's a completely different error - it's a runtime error, not a linker error.  You are, evidently, accessing beyond the bounds of a `string`.  `char c0 = s[i-1]` looks mighty suspicious, when `i` is zero.

Comment: yup, i think that's the problem , because same error is coming also in eclipse.                       But how codelite IDE is not generating anything . it gives right output???

Comment: use g++ to compile. Also add flag "--std=c++11 "

Comment: Accessing out of bounds is UB.  You can't predict what is going to happen.